# Max size limit for custom Properties for outlook web add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am in the processing of developing an outlook web addin. For part of the functionality we need to store some custom properties with the meeting item.

It seems that there is a hard limit of 2500 characters for all customproperties in total, which I found by a bit of trial and error, and also by digging the the JS files used by the addin and finding this function:

```
   r.CustomProperties.prototype.saveAsync = function() {
        for (var i = [], t = 0; t < arguments.length; ++t)
            i[t] = arguments[t];
        var f = 2500;
        if (window.JSON.stringify(this._data$p$0).length > f)
            throw Error.argument();
        var n = r.CommonParameters.parse(i, !1, !0);
        if (window.OSF.DDA.OutlookAppOm._instance$p.shouldRunNewCode(r.ShouldRunNewCodeForFlags.saveCustomProperties))
            window.OSF.DDA.OutlookAppOm._instance$p._standardInvokeHostMethod$i$0(4, {
                customProperties: this._data$p$0
            }, null, n._asyncContext$p$0, n._callback$p$0);
        else {
            var u = new r.SaveDictionaryRequest(n._callback$p$0,n._asyncContext$p$0);
            u._sendRequest$i$0(4, "SaveCustomProperties", {
                customProperties: this._data$p$0
            })
        }
    }
```

Has anyone found another method that would allow us to save more than 2500 characters? If we could quadruple that limit, that would be about right; because of the sensitive nature of the data we are storing we would rather not introduce another database if we can avoid it (instead relying on the security we already have around Microsoft Exchange).

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting findings, but the limit is set in JS function with exposes functionality to set/save custom properties. I didn't fund in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview) any mentions of this limit. Microsoft should update the documentation to indicate this limit.

If you need to store more information with the message, as a workaround, you can use EWS request (more at "[Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services)") or REST (more at "[Outlook Extended Properties REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extended-properties-rest-operations)") call. You will be able to set custom/extended property without this limit, especially if you would use "Binaty" type.